# React onComponentDidMount event with react-redux connect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In the below example, *onComponentDidMount* does not work because that event does not exist in React. Assuming I don't want to rewrite Main using React.Component, what event should I use, or is there another way?

```
let Main = ({myEventMethod}) => (
    <main onComponentDidMount={myEventMethod}>
        ...
    </main>
)

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    myEventMethod: () => {...}
})

Main = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DOCS:**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions)

> Stateless Functions do not have the component lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

Higher Order Components come to rescue. [Demo](https://codepen.io/tarabyte/pen/dXZmJX).

```
const withComponentDidMount = handler => Cmp => {
  class WithComponentDidMount extends Component {
    render() {
      return <Cmp {...this.props}/>
    }
  }

  WithComponentDidMount.prototype.componentDidMount = handler

  return WithComponentDidMount
}

const Wrapped = withComponentDidMount(function() {
  console.log('Mount')
})(App)
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand. Can you please put it in the context of my example?

Comment: Which part you don't understand? BTW there is a demo you can fork and play with.

Comment: So I use this instead of connect?

Comment: With connect. HOCs can be composed `connect(...)(withComponentDidMount(myEventMethod)(Main))`

Comment: Ok now I see. Although I would rather just extend React.Component